# Contact form - Passing variables from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

[I suspect the issue at hand has to do with how the php array gets passed to jQuery, if that isn't the case I apologize for the misleading title]

The contact form below is working -- except when I submit the forms' data, sometimes one field always keeps its red border indicating missing input, even when it actually has data.

To elaborate: I have a working php-only solution but on submit it causes a page-reload which I would like to avoid. After some research, it seems I need php/jQuery/ajax to perform these things asynchronously and to stay on the same site.

**Desired behaviour:**
So there are three required input fields called name, email and message, if any one is left out, it should receive a red border and no email gets sent.

**Actual behaviour:**
If for example only name and message are filled out and submitted, the empty email field is colored red.
But if a (valid) email is provided, the second submit action *does not* remove the red border around the email field.

I know that javascript and friends is a client-side language, and PHP gets processed server-side. Once the form is submitted, the .ajax function takes the serialized form values, uses 'POST' to stuff it into the php script and waits for the server to call us back inside .done()

This is where I'm lost - how is the php array to be used in jQuery?

E.g. no matter what, this line is never reached:

```
console.log("All fields filled and valid");
```

## **index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />

<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="verify.js"></script>

    <style>
        .input-error
        {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>        

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()                // Wait until website (DOM) is completely loaded
        {    
            /* Page top */
            $('#pagetop').click(function()
            {
                console.log(this);
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 600);
                return false;
            });     
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>  
    <!-- action is left blank as process.php is called from verify.js -->
    <form action="" method="POST" id="contactForm">     

        <label for="company">Company</label>    
        <br>                
        <input type="text" style="width: 904px; height: 24px;" id="company" name="company" value="">
        <br><br>                            

        <label for="name">Name *</label>    
        <br>                
        <input type="text" style="width: 904px; height: 24px;" id="name" name="user_name" value="">
        <br><br>            

        <label for="email">Email *</label>  
        <br>            
        <input type="text" style="width: 904px; height: 24px;" id="email" name="user_email" value="">
        <br><br>            

        <label for="message">Message *</label>
        <br>
        <textarea style="width: 904px; resize: none;" rows="9" id="message" name="user_message"></textarea>
        <br><br>                                

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        <br><br>

    </form>
</body>
```

## **verify.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    // process the form
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(event) 
    {               
        //$('#name, #email, #message').removeClass('input-error'); 

        // process the form
        $.ajax(
        {
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : $('#contactForm').serialize(),
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) 
        {
            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data);              

             if (data.errors.name) 
             {
                 console.log("Name missing"); 
                 $('#name').addClass('input-error'); 
             }
             else
             {
                 $('#name').removeClass('input-error'); 
             }

             // handle errors for email
             if (data.errors.email) 
             {
                 console.log("Email missing or invalid"); 
                 $('#email').addClass('input-error'); 
             }
             else
             {
                 $('#email').removeClass('input-error'); 
             }

             // handle errors for message
             if (data.errors.message) 
             {
                 console.log("Message missing"); 
                 $('#message').addClass('input-error'); 
             }
             else
             {
                 $('#message').removeClass('input-error'); 
             }


             if(data.input_valid == true)
             {          
                 console.log("All fields filled and valid"); 
                 alert('success');      
             }      
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

## **process.php**

```
<?php

    $errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
    $data           = array();      // array to pass back data

    // Sanitize input variables 
    $company = test_input($_POST['company']);
    $name = test_input($_POST['user_name']);
    $email = test_input($_POST['user_email']);
    $message = test_input($_POST['user_message']);


    // Validate the variables 
    // If any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

    if (empty($name))       
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

    if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        $errors['email'] = 'Valid Email is required.';

    if (empty($message))
        $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';


    $from = '--- Contact Form ---'; 
    $to = 'some@mail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Form'; 
    $body = "From: $name\nCompany: $company\nE-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n\n$message";

    // return a response ===========================================================

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
    if(!empty($errors)) 
    {
        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['input_valid'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // If there are no errors process our form, then return a message
        $data['input_valid'] = true;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
        {
            $data['message'] = 'Thank you for your message!';
            $data['mail_sent'] = true;
        } 
        else    
        {
            $data['message'] = 'Message could not be sent - please try again later.';
            $data['mail_sent'] = false;
        }
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);


    // Convert special characters to html entities to prevent XSS attacks
    // Also remove white-space and backslashes
    function test_input($val) 
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        $val = stripslashes($val);
        $val = htmlspecialchars($val);
        return $val;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault();` as the first line inside `$('#contactForm').submit(function(event) {` for a start... That will prevent the page from reloading. Then, if there still is an issue, update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if all validations pass in your php script, then `data['errors']` is never defined. This might cause an error to be thrown (that you can see in the browser console) in the javascript when you write:

```
if (data.errors.name)
```

`data.errors` will evaluate to `undefined` in javascript, and when you try to access a property of `undefined` like `data.errors.name`, it will throw an error and stop the script.

To fix this, you probably just need to define errors in your php script, (though I'm not 100% sure the JSON methods won't leave out an empty array...). Try doing this in your php script:

```
if(!empty($errors)) 
{
    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['input_valid'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} 
else 
{
    // If there are no errors process our form, then return a message
    $data['input_valid'] = true;
    $data['errors'] = $errors; // even though it is empty
    // etc
```

Comment: Your analysis is reasonable; adding the line "$data['errors'] = $errors;" didn't help though. I will try defining the error strings separately and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to see errors in your browser console? If I am right, you would see an error something like "cannot access property name of undefined" and a reference to a specific line of your script.

Comment: I use firefox -> F12 -> console. No "undefined" messages at any point. I will take a close look at what the php script does with xdebug and report back.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I don't know if it will work with your jquery version but just in case it doesn't, place this code in your header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I used the below code and it worked. Sent the email without having to change the PHP code:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function(event)  {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data)  {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.input_valid == true) {
                console.log("All fields filled and valid");
                // If the function is a success remove error classes from all fields
                // you can either place the below code above the alert so that it happens
                // before you get the success message, or after.
                $('#name').removeClass('input-error');
                $('#email').removeClass('input-error');
                $('#message').removeClass('input-error');
                alert('success');
            } else {
                if (data.errors.name)  {
                    console.log("Name missing");
                    $('#name').addClass('input-error');
                } else {
                    $('#name').removeClass('input-error');
                }
                if (data.errors.email)  {
                    console.log("Email missing or invalid");
                    $('#email').addClass('input-error');
                } else {
                    $('#email').removeClass('input-error');
                }
                if (data.errors.message) {
                    console.log("Message missing");
                    $('#message').addClass('input-error');
                } else {
                    $('#message').removeClass('input-error');
                }
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you; ideally, I would like to keep  the code mostly as is and find out why I don't hit the "success" part in verify.js (the part that begins with if(data.input_valid == true) ...